# Constructing a tuple of length n from a sequence of parser combinators

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators

- **Question.** Is there a way to define an operator such that a sequence of values separated by that operator yields a flat tuple?

I have struggled to find a concise phrasing of my question, so read on for details and examples...

### Description

I'm writing myself a few helper operators for Parsec, starting with the following:

```
(<@) :: GenParser tok st a -> (a -> b) -> GenParser tok st b
p <@ f = do {
    x <- p ;
    return (f x)
}

(<>) :: GenParser tok st a -> GenParser tok st b -> GenParser tok st (a, b)
p <> q = do {
    x <- p ;
    y <- q ;
    return (x, y)
 }
```

These work as follows:

```
parseTest ((many upper) <@ length) "HELLO"
5

parseTest (many upper) <> (many lower) "ABCdef"
("ABC", "def")
```

Unfortunately, a sequence of parsers separated by `<>` will result in a nested tuple, e.g.:

```
parseTest (subject <> verb <> object) "edmund learns haskell"
(("edmund", "learns"), "haskell")
```

Instead of the relatively more cromulent:

```
("edmund", "learns", "haskell")
```

I'm looking for a way to define `<>` so that

```
p1 :: GenParser tok st a ; p2 :: GenParser tok st b ; p3 :: GenParser tok st c
p1 <> p2 :: GenParser tok st (a, b)
p1 <> p2 <> p3:: GenParser tok st (a, b, c)
...
```

I do not think I have ever seen a Haskell program where a tuple type of length `n` (known at compile time) is constructed like this.  And I suspect it may be difficult to define the operator with both types:

```
GenParser tok st a -> GenParser tok st b) -> GenParser tok st (a, b)
GenParser tok st (a, b) -> GenParser tok st c) -> GenParser tok st (a, b, c)
```

-- how does one tell, at compile time, the difference between a tuple resulting from `<>`, and one which is simply the intended return type from any other parser?  I can only speculate that additional syntax would be required.

So, I am not at all sure it's a good idea or even possible.  I would be curious to know how to do it even if it is not a good idea for my case (and I would love to know how to if it's impossible!).

- **Followup question** (if this crazy scheme is possible)**.** How could one annotate one item in a chain of `<>`s to be left out of the result tuple?

For example, assuming a postfix annotation `<#`:

```
p1 :: GenParser tok st a
p2 :: GenParser tok st b
p1 <> keyword "is" <# <> p2 :: GenParser tok st (a, b)
```

### Background

Circa 2006 I learned about parser combinators at university.  We used a library in which the `<@`, and I believe the `<>` operator, were present and performed similarly to my attempts.  I do not know what this library was; it may have been written by a graduate student for teaching our class.  In any case, it does not seem to be either Parsec nor the base parser combinators in `Text.Parser.Combinators.

- **Bonus question.** What is the difference between the base parser combinators in `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`/`ReadPrec` and the ones in Parsec?

I seem to recall this library was also nondeterministic, with each parser invocation returning the set of possible parses and the remaining unparsed input for each.  (A successful, complete, unambiguous parse would result in `[(parseresult, "")]`.)

- **Final question.** If this sounds like something you've heard of, could you let me know what it was (for nostalgia's sake) ?

Comment: Well done for thinking right and provoking an excellent answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Functor

I’d like to direct your attention to something:

```
(<@)      :: GenParser tok st a -> (a -> b) -> GenParser tok st b
flip fmap :: (Functor f) => f a -> (a -> b) -> f                b
```

Do you notice a similarity? If we replace `f` with `GenParser tok st` in the type of `flip fmap`, we get the type of `(<@)`. Furthermore, this is not theoretical: `GenParser tok st` is an instance of [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Functor.html). `fmap` is also available in operator form, named `<$>`. So, we can rewrite your code in two ways (original first):

```
ghci> parseTest ((many upper) <@ length) "HELLO"
5
ghci> parseTest (fmap length (many upper)) "HELLO"
5
ghci> parseTest (length <$> (many upper)) "HELLO"
5
```

## Applicative

Functors are nice, but they aren’t powerful enough to subsume your second example. Fortunately, there is another typeclass that is: [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html). Now, `Applicative` does not have a function to form a monadic action yielding a pair out of two monadic actions, but it *does* provide some helpful building blocks. In particular, it provides `<*>`:

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It turns out that we can compose this together with `<$>` to rewrite your second example:

```
ghci> parseTest (many upper) <> (many lower) "ABCdef"
("ABC", "def")
ghci> parseTest ((,) <$> many upper <*> many lower) "ABCdef"
("ABC", "def")
```

If you’re not familiar with the syntax, `(,)` is the function that creates a pair; it has type `a -> b -> (a, b)`.

But `Applicative` does not stop there. You were looking for a way to flatten a tuple; but rather than creating nested tuples and flattening them out, you can use `Applicative` to create a triple directly:

```
ghci> parseTest ((,,) <$> subject <*> verb <*> object) "edmund learns haskell"
("edmund", "learns", "haskell")
```

And it just happens that `Applicative` has *another* operator to help you with your last request, too: `<*` and `*>`, which ignore the result of the second or the result of the first operand, respectively. So if you want to ignore the verb:

```
ghci> parseTest ((,) <$> subject <* verb <*> object) "edmund learns haskell"
("edmund", "haskell")
```

## Bonus question

If I recall correctly, `ReadP` allows backtracking at each step; Parsec, on the other hand, does not allow backtracking unless you directly or indirectly annotate it in your parser using the `try` combinator or some other combinator that uses that combinator. As such, Parsec parsers do not backtrack as much, and can have better worst-case performance.

---

## Appendix: Implementing your `<>`…almost <sup><sub>*(not for the faint of heart)*</sub></sup>

I don’t know of any way to implement your *exact* `<>`, or to make it work for *all* sizes of tuples, but if you’re willing to enable a few Haskell extensions, you can eliminate the need for counting, working up to an arbitrary but fixed size of tuples. First, we’ll want to have a type for a 1-tuple:

```
newtype One a = One a deriving (Eq, Read, Show)  -- derive more if you want
```

Now, we want a function with these types:

```
(<>) :: (Applicative f) => f ()        -> f a -> f (One a)
(<>) :: (Applicative f) => f (One a)   -> f b -> f (a, b)
(<>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a, b)    -> f c -> f (a, b, c)
(<>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a, b, c) -> f d -> f (a, b, c, d)
-- ...
```

How do we have a function with multiple types in Haskell? Typeclasses, of course! But an ordinary typeclass won’t do it: we need functional dependencies. Also, I can’t think of an appropriate name, so I’ll just call it `C`. <sup><sub>*(If you can think of a better name, tell me in the comments and I’ll edit.)*</sub></sup>

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
class C a b c | a b -> c, c -> a b where
    (<>) :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f c
```

Then, to actually implement our instances, we need `FlexibleInstances`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance C ()        a (One a)      where (<>) _ = fmap One
instance C (One a)   b (a, b)       where (<>) = liftA2 $ \(One a)   b -> (a, b)
instance C (a, b)    c (a, b, c)    where (<>) = liftA2 $ \(a, b)    c -> (a, b, c)
instance C (a, b, c) d (a, b, c, d) where (<>) = liftA2 $ \(a, b, c) d -> (a, b, c, d)
-- ...
```

Now you can write your parsers like this:

```
parseTest (return () <> subject <> verb <> object) "edmund learns haskell"
("edmund", "learns", "haskell")
```

We did have to write `return () <>` before it, which is undesirable. You could retain your prior implementation of `<>` and rename our new implementation to `<+>`, and then you could write your parsers like this:

```
parseTest (subject <+> verb <> object) "edmund learns haskell"
("edmund", "learns", "haskell")
```

(`<+>` used to join all parsers after the first two) There might be a way to make a single operator do it using `OverlappingInstances`, but the obvious solution violates the functional dependencies.

### The question that needs to be asked

If you’re considering using this latter approach, I advise you not to. First, if you’re going to use tuples, it’s not that difficult to count the number of items you want to parse. Second, you often won’t be using tuples in the first place, and this approach only works if you are trying to get tuples. But what makes more sense than a tuple? Well, an AST node. For example, if you were writing a parser for a programming language, you might have a type like this:

```
data Expression = ...
                | IfExpression Expression Expression Expression
                | ...
                deriving (...)
```

Then, to parse it, you can use `Applicative`:

```
parseIfExpression = IfExpression
                <$> keyword "if"    *> expression
                <*  keyword "then" <*> expression
                <*  keyword "else" <*> expression
```

Here, we don’t need to count the number of items; it’s encapsulated in the type of the `IfExpression` type constructor. Since normally you’re going to be parsing ASTs, tuples are going to be irrelevant, and so such a complex solution seems unjustified, particularly since the alternative when you have to use tuples is so uncomplicated (counting the number of items and inserting the appropriate tuple constructor).

Comment: Thank you!  That is a very comprehensive answer.  Though it does seem I would need to use the `(,)`, `(,,)`, ... functions instead of finding a way for the type system to figure out what kind of tuple I wanted simply from the number of items in the expression.  The more I think about it, it was an unreasonable request: in my original example, `<>` would need to have an infinite number of types of the form `(GenParser tok st a, ..., GenParser tok st y) -> GenParser tok st z -> (GenParser tok st a, ..., GenParser tok st z)` -- unless you know a clever trick for that, too?

Comment: @Edmund: I don’t think there’s a way to make it work for tuples of all sizes, but I found a way to do it up to an arbitrarily chosen size of tuples using typeclasses and the `FunctionalDependencies` and `FlexibleInstances` extensions. (Alternatively, it could probably use associated types.) That said, using `Applicative` in this case is idiomatic. I don’t know what you plan to do with the tuples, but for parsing languages, many forego the tuples to directly generate ASTs, e.g. `IfStatement <$> keyword "if" *> expression <* keyword "then" <*> expression <* keyword "else" <*> expression`.

Comment: This is a fabulous answer and needs more upvotes. This is _the_ answer on combining sequences of parsers. I do so wholeheartedly approve.

Comment: @icktoofay: I wasn't expecting to use my own convoluted combinators for my parsing problem, but I did need to explore a bit further than the obvious, to see what was possible and to warm up after so long. `:)`  The scheme in your appendix looks perfect for my actual application, and definitely saves on packing and unpacking tuples (something I did expect to end up doing).